# Matplotlib ``figure.titlesize`` rcParam

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to update my matplotlib rcParams.  According to http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html, the option should be present, but it is not. These are the items I can find in my rcParam file:

```
      u'figure.autolayout': False,
      u'figure.dpi': 80.0,
      u'figure.edgecolor': u'w',
      u'figure.facecolor': u'0.75',
      u'figure.figsize': [46.666666666666664, 35.0],
      u'figure.frameon': True,
      u'figure.max_open_warning': 20,
      u'figure.subplot.bottom': 0.1,
      u'figure.subplot.hspace': 0.2,
      u'figure.subplot.left': 0.125,
      u'figure.subplot.right': 0.9,
      u'figure.subplot.top': 0.9,
      u'figure.subplot.wspace': 0.2,
```

Has this feature been removed or is it somehow hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a new option added between `v1.4.3` and `v1.5.x`. For example, compare the code on github for [`v1.4.3`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v1.4.3-doc/lib/matplotlib/rcsetup.py#L702), with [`v1.5.x`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v1.5.x/lib/matplotlib/rcsetup.py#L1039).

The documentation you linked to must be for `v1.5.x`. So, maybe you could upgrade to `v1.5.x` if you need that option?